# Select Tab on form initialization

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

This is stupid and I did it before, but now its not working and I cant find a solution online. I have a form and one tab page. on the tab page there are 4 tabs. how can I make the 4th tab selected when the form loads? I also want to use the tab's text, or name, and not the tab index.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the tab in your form constructor.  The boilerplate code is:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4;
        // or:
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;
    }
```

Comment: Thanx! The tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage4 is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the tabs to find the one you want, then set the TabControl's `SelectedTab` property.